# Chef "RecipeNotFound" exception when run chef-client as Windows service

Tags: chef-infra

I have a simple cookbook named "foo" with a simple recipe in t recipes/default.rb.

I can run the cookbook/recipe manually by typing "chef-client -o foo" and the recipe is behaving as expected (The recipe is just a test to try to understand how Chef-client processes cookbooks/recipes and it just writes to a file).

I've installed the chef-client as a Windows service, and it is starting and running, but in Event Viewer, I am seeing this error:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Chef
Date:          6/29/2015 12:53:45 PM
Event ID:      10003
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      WIN-NFJMV7R6OLU
Description:
Failed Chef Client run 336b73ca-7a27-4366-8a8e-f33b23e214ff in 0.265201 seconds.
 Exception type: Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
 Exception message: could not find recipe default.rb for cookbook foo
 Exception backtrace: c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:217:in `load_recipe'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:173:in `load_recipe'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:140:in `block in compile_recipes'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `each'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `compile_recipes'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:75:in `compile'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:96:in `load'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:87:in `setup_run_context'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:256:in `setup_run_context'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:454:in `run'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:253:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:230:in `block in run_chef_client'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:39:in `with_server_connectivity'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:213:in `run_chef_client'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:375:in `run_application'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
c:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:63:in `load'
c:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:63:in `<main>'

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Chef" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">10003</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-06-29T19:53:45.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>947</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>WIN-NFJMV7R6OLU</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>336b73ca-7a27-4366-8a8e-f33b23e214ff</Data>
    <Data>0.265201</Data>
    <Data>Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound</Data>
    <Data>could not find recipe default.rb for cookbook foo</Data>
    <Data>c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:217:in `load_recipe'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:173:in `load_recipe'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:140:in `block in compile_recipes'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `each'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `compile_recipes'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:75:in `compile'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:96:in `load'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:87:in `setup_run_context'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:256:in `setup_run_context'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:454:in `run'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:253:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:230:in `block in run_chef_client'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:39:in `with_server_connectivity'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:213:in `run_chef_client'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:375:in `run_application'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:26:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;'
c:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:63:in `load'
c:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:63:in `&lt;main&gt;'</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

It seems like, when the Chef-client is run manually, it can find the recipe, but if it is run as a Windows service, for some reason, Chef-client can't find the recipes/default.rb?

Is there somethng else that I need to do to the recipe or cookbook in order to make it work with chef-client as a service?

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT:  Also, here is what knife, which run on my Chef workstation, shows for the node:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo> knife node show node3
Node Name:   node3
Environment: _default
FQDN:        WIN-NFJMV7R6OLU
IP:          192.168.0.84
Run List:    recipe[foo::default.rb]
Roles:
Recipes:
Platform:    windows 6.1.7601
Tags:
```

EDIT 2:

Also, here's the chef-stacktrace.out from the node:

```
Generated at 2015-06-29 17:08:23 -0400
Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound: could not find recipe default.rb for cookbook foo
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:217:in `load_recipe'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:173:in `load_recipe'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:140:in `block in compile_recipes'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `each'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `compile_recipes'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:75:in `compile'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:96:in `load'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:87:in `setup_run_context'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:256:in `setup_run_context'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:454:in `run'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:253:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:230:in `block in run_chef_client'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:39:in `with_server_connectivity'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:213:in `run_chef_client'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:375:in `run_application'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
c:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:63:in `load'
c:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:63:in `<main>'
```

EDIT 3:

OK, I *GOT IT WORKING*, but I don't understand why/how :(...

What happened was that I was trying to figure out what might be going on, and I happened to be looking at the management web app and saw that in the lower left box, "current cookbooks", it had an entry for JUST "foo".

So, I dragged the "foo" over to the right pane and deleted the "foo::default.rb".

Then, I waited, and sure enough, it started working...  I started seeing Chef client run in Event viewer with no errors and also the recipe was writing to the hard drive (my test case).

Now, :

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo> knife node show node3
Node Name:   node3
Environment: _default
FQDN:        WIN-NFJMV7R6OLU
IP:          192.168.0.84
Run List:    recipe[foo]
Roles:
Recipes:     foo, foo::default
Platform:    windows 6.1.7601
Tags:
PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo>
```

So I'm glad it's working, but I'm puzzled why it wasn't working before???

Is this a bug in Chef-client?

Also, remember this worked when I ran chef-client from the command line... it just failed when run as a service.

Comment: The run_list in the first `knife node show` looks odd to me. I'd expect `recipe[foo::default]` and not `recipe[foo::default.rb]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sneal is absolutely correct. In a runlist you leave out the .rb of the recipe name. Also, if you leave out the recipe name entirely, as in

```
recipe[foo]
```

it will assume you're looking for foo::default. I highly recommend always including the recipe name, mind you, I'm just trying to explain some behavior that would seem strange otherwise.